# DataGridView filtering CLR c++

Tags: .net, datagridview, c++-cli, clr

I have created a very basic program with 4 columns in a `DataGridView` as shown below.
I would have embedded the image but don't have enough reputation yet.

[image: Example Program]
<sub>(source: [amicableits.com](http://amicableits.com/stackexchange/Filter%20Sample%20Program.png))</sub>

I am attempting to create a filter based on the First Name so as the user enters a value in the TextBox next to FirstName's Filter, the FirstNames in the `DataGridView` will be filtered to help in searching for specific values. I will apply the filter across all my columns but for now I just need to grasp the concept with one example. After lot's of searching on the internet I have seen users create datatables separately, read the data from a file and then create a view (or something along those lines).

I have also seen users bind data from a database. What I'm after I guess is a solution to filter data already in the `DataGridView`.

I have added the rows to the `DataGridView` programmatically as shown below:

```
    this->dataGridView1->Rows->Add("1","Jack","Brown",true);
    this->dataGridView1->Rows->Add("2","Jason","Brown",false);
    this->dataGridView1->Rows->Add("3","Adam","Babson",true);
    this->dataGridView1->Rows->Add("4","Pablo","Favor",false);
    this->dataGridView1->Rows->Add("5","Tony","Jones",true);
    this->dataGridView1->Rows->Add("6","Jessica","Sason",true);
```

The Visual Studio example program can also be [downloaded here](http://amicableits.com/stackexchange/datagrid_filter%20source.zip)

Any assistance appreciated.
Alternatively if someone can tell me how I can create a dataview of existing data in a datagridview this may also help I believe.

Comment: Always separate the model from the view.  Keep the data in a separate collection, filtering is now trivial.

Answer (score 0):

What about simply handling it by hand :

when the user updates the filter you search for the rows that match it and hide the other ones by setting the **Visible** flag to false.

Comment: The datagridview example given was only the simplest of examples. I want to be able to use the data in a datagridview, apply a view to it and run the rowfilter operations on the view. Filtering it manually really is not an option for me.The problem is getting the data already present in the datagridview to a dataview object.[Click Here for more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter.aspx)